# Find last occurence in text formula

Tags: text

I need to find the last occurrence of the character comma for retrieve last word of a text field.

Example.

Text field: `Discovery 3.0 SDV6 188KW Diesel (HP) SE, Italy ITA, HSVH/350HG, **2012**`

The formula results get last word: 2012

Comment: after last comma always you will get Year ie. 2012 or 2015 or 2016 ?

Comment: the year is not the same for all records

Comment: Means it will only last 4 character correct?

Comment: It may be that the year also contains other characters. I'm interested in all the characters after the last comma

Comment: What is the current and the expected output?? Could you show with 2-3 examples?

Comment: I solved with this formula : RIGHT(RIGHT(RIGHT(Descrizione__c, LEN(Descrizione__c) - FIND(",", Descrizione__c)), LEN(RIGHT(Descrizione__c, LEN(Descrizione__c) - FIND(",", Descrizione__c))) - FIND(",", RIGHT(Descrizione__c, LEN(Descrizione__c) - FIND(",", Descrizione__c)))), LEN(RIGHT(RIGHT(Descrizione__c, LEN(Descrizione__c) - FIND(",", Descrizione__c)), LEN(RIGHT(Descrizione__c, LEN(Descrizione__c) - FIND(",", Descrizione__c))) - FIND(",", RIGHT(Descrizione__c, LEN(Descrizione__c) - FIND(",", Descrizione__c)))))-FIND(",",RIGHT(RIGHT(Descrizione__c, LEN(Descrizione__c) - continue

Comment: - FIND(",", Descrizione__c)), LEN(RIGHT(Descrizione__c, LEN(Descrizione__c) - FIND(",", Descrizione__c))) - FIND(",", RIGHT(Descrizione__c, LEN(Descrizione__c) - FIND(",", Descrizione__c))))))

Comment: this is a very fragile solution as I'm sure you realize as it is dependent on # of commas in text field; apex is more robust (a before insert/update trigger)

Answer (score 1):

Query the Object and your text field and use the below code snippet. This should work for you.

```
List<String> lstStr = Your_Object_name.Your_File.Name.split(',');
system.debug('--Your desired Result--'+lstStr[lstStr.size()-1]);
```